# What are race conditions in salesforce

Tags: soql

Could any body let me know that what are race  conditions that are being prevented by Record Locking? IF possible please let me know at least one example.

Comment: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Bqpv

Comment: http://www.thecvsi.com/concurrent-access-race-condition-salesforce-insert-operation/ - Lots of information via a google search or a search on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example would be if you wanted to implement your own sequence number algorithm that requires a query to get the current value, and then an update of that value with one added. If two requests - R1 and R2 - come in close together, then R1 reads the value V, then R2 reads the same value V, then R1 updates with V+1, then R2 updates with V+1. So one of the updates is lost.

By doing the query that reads the sequence value with [for update](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_locking_statements.htm) applied, the reads and updates are be forced to be sequential: R1 reads V then updates to V+1 then R2 reads V+1 then updates to V+2 (the desired outcome).

See the [for-update](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/for-update) tag on this site for lots more detail.